# Browser compatibility in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have created a small webpage, where I would like to animate content using jQuery during navigation. It's working perfectly in Internet Explorer. If I use Firefox it's not working properly.

My code is as follows

```
$("#maincontent").animate({"top":"450px"},800, function(){
    $("#maincontent").html($("#"+Lidentity).html())
        .animate({"top":"-10px"},600)
        .animate({"top":"10px"},100)
        .animate({"top":"-5px"},100)
        .animate({"top":"5px"},100)
        .animate({"top":"0px"},100);
});
```

I have set the `#maincontent` element position as absolute.

Comment: what actually happens in firefox? nothing? Do you have Firebug installed in Firefox? It will help you track down the error.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make it look like it bounces with your animation, you're much better off using the easings from jQuery UI.

Example (based off your code):

```
$("#maincontent").animate({"top":"450px"},800, function(){
    $("#maincontent").html($("#"+Lidentity).html())
        .animate({"top":"0px"},800,"easeOutBounce");
});
```

Obviously for this to work you also need to add a reference to jQuery.UI (either the full bundle or at least effects.core.js & effects.bounce.js)